# SQL JOIN and WHERE Not working in this scenario

Tags: c#, sql, join

I'm writing a SQL query to get Pictures posted by people from **Table A** if they are a noted as a friend in **Table B**

> 1) Get All Posts from a Table A
>
> 2) Check if the UserID is listed in Table B
>
> 3) Return results from Table A

This is what I tried:

*user = me in this scenario and FriendID is another person

```
Select * from ActivityTable JOIN FriendsTable ON ActivityTable.UserID=FriendsTable.FriendID WHERE FriendsTable.UserID='" + user + "'"
```

FriendsTable Columns: id, UserID, FriendID

ActivityTable Columns: id, UserID, Content

Therefore, if Mary is listed as a friend of mine in the column FriendID and I'm listed in the column UserID, Get All Activities of Mary from Table A. (So on and so forth for every person who is a friend)

**SAMPLE DATA:**

id:            2412

UserID:    Roger

FriendID: Emily

**Activity Sample Data:**

id: 23523

UserID: Emily

Content: Hello there

Therefore, return the rows that has Emily as a UserID since Emily is listed as a friend

Comment: Dont use string concatenation to build your sql query and to pass parameters. Instead use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection and other issues.

Comment: Yeah I use them. I'm using this for now till I get the query right @TimSchmelter

Comment: What is returned when you just do: select * from FriendsTable where UserID='{username}'  what if you change the equal to "like"

Comment: *Why doesn't my query work?* Please elaborate. What *specifically* is wrong.

Comment: If your IDs are integers then you don't want the single quotes around the vale you check against. Add some sample data to your post perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @uid nvarchar(25) = 'Roger'

select a.* from ActivityTable a inner join FriendsTable f
  on a.UserID = f.FriendID
where f.UserID = @uid
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @user nvarchar(50) = 'Roger'

Select act.* from ActivityTable act JOIN FriendsTable fr ON act.UserID=fr.FriendID WHERE fr.UserID='" + @user + "'"